# Can 'docker-compose down' be somehow prevented from running in production?

Tags: docker, zsh

I really don't want it to be possible to run `docker-compose down` in production. Ever. Is there a way to overwrite that command either in zsh or otherwise that will just throw an error if run on the production server?

We tried to alias the command to something else but to no avail.

Comment: What is docker down?

Comment: @michael_bitard Docker down is the command to essentially destroy all the docker containers. It could wipe production data and seems dangerous to leave available.

Comment: Ow, this is a docker-compose command, not a docker one

Comment: Ah my bad! edited to be accurate.

Comment: Only root users or explicitly granted users can do this.   Do you alias rm -rf as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you're not doing this for security purposes? You can control which user can and cannot manage docker services (and therefore docker-compose) by adding/removing them from the docker group.

If you want to prevent yourself from accidentally running `docker-compose down`, you can write a wrapper script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for arg in "$@";do
    if [[ "$arg" = "down" ]];then
        >&2 echo "ERROR: 'docker-compose down' has been disabled!"
        exit 1
    fi
done
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose "$@"   # Adapt to actual path to docker-compose binary if different
```

Put this as `docker-compose` in a location early in your `$PATH`, e.g. `$HOME/bin/docker-compose`and make it executable. It will exit with a warning to STDERR if the command line contains `down`.

However, this will not prevent anyone with malicious intents and the necessary permissions to call the real docker-compose binary directly.

Comment: That's great - thank you - it's just to prevent accidents.